# Как в JavaFX растянуть во высоте дочерний компонент таким образом, чтобы он ничего не знал о компоновке, в которой он находится?

Tags: java, javafx

В рамках упражнения "Приложение TODO List" собираюсь сделать приложение с таким внешним видом (отрисовано в SceneBuilder; что-то не так отступами вокруг кнопки "Add new", но это я потом разберусь):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При таком FXML-коде корневого компонента:

```xml
<SplitPane
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/13"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
  prefHeight="640.0"
  prefWidth="640.0"
  dividerPositions="0.5"
>

  <!-- === Left section ============================================================================================ -->
  <VBox>
    <fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TasksList/TasksList.fxml"/>
    <ButtonBar>
      <buttons><Button text="Add new" /></buttons>
      <padding><Insets left="12.0" right="12.0"/></padding>
      <VBox.margin><Insets top="6.0" /></VBox.margin>
    </ButtonBar>
  </VBox>

  <!-- === Right section =========================================================================================== -->
  <SplitPane
    dividerPositions="0.5"
    orientation="VERTICAL"
    VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"
  >

    <!-- === Right top subsection ================================================================================== -->
    <VBox>
      <fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TaskViewer/TaskViewer.fxml"/>
      <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <buttons>
          <Button text="Edit"/>
          <Button text="Delete"/>
        </buttons>
        <padding><Insets left="12.0" right="12.0"/></padding>
      </ButtonBar>
    </VBox>

    <!-- === Right bottom subsection =============================================================================== -->
    <VBox>
      <fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TaskEditor/TaskEditor.fxml" />
      <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <buttons><Button text="Save"/></buttons>
        <VBox.margin><Insets left="12.0" right="12.0"/></VBox.margin>
      </ButtonBar>
    </VBox>
  </SplitPane>
</SplitPane>
```

реальное приложение в текущем состоянии выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Список карточек (TasksList) и панель просмотра таска (TaskViewer) не заполняют всё предоставленное им место, потому что содержимое подключений `<fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TasksList/TasksList.fxml"/>` и `<fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TaskViewer/TaskViewer.fxml"/>` ничего не знает **и не должно знать** о том, в какую компоновку они вложено. Не должны знать потому, что это нарушает концепцию переиспользования компонентов, то есть разрабатывая компонент, мы заранее не знаем, где его будут использовать. В зависимости от контекста, мы можем захотеть один и тот компонент на разных экранах приложения:

- Растянуть до максимальной высоты родителя
- Растянуть до заданной максимальной высоты
- Сделать так, чтобы он не растягивался
- Спозиционировать абсолютно

Конкретно в данном случае, `TaskList` и `TaskViewer` ничего не знают о том, будут ли они растягиваться или нет - это решает тот компонент, который их использует.
А вот каким образом это решает в JavaFX, иными словами, каким образом будет передавать `TaskList` и `TaskViewer` параметр, отвечающий за связанное с использованием доступного пространства поведением, это я и хочу спросить.

### Ход моих мыслей по поводу данной проблемы

#### Как эта проблема решается в веб-разработке

Лучшее на мой взгляд решение предлагает методология [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/). Там, при использовании компонента (допустим `TaksList`) добавляется контекстный CSS-класс (например, `MainLayout-TasksList`). В частности, этот класс может содержать правила, растягивающие этот компонент по высоте внутри родительского контейнера.  Примерно так бы это выглядело во Vue, дающего возможность определять компоненты и добавлять их в шаблон как новые тэги с поддержкой верхнего регистра:

```html
<div class="MainLayout">
  <div class="MainLayout-LeftSection">
    <TasksList class="MainLayout-TasksList"></TasksList>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="MainLayout-RightSection">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Ещё многие разработчики (особенно начинающие) часто для задания геометрии используют обёртки. Но часто этими обёртками злоупотребляют, а чем больше тэгов в HTML-коде, тем сложнее установить соответствие между тем, что видишь и кодом. Поэтому в веб-разработке я использую минимум обёрток, а БЭМ-овский способ предпочтительный.

#### Что мне уже известно об ограничениях JavaFX

Скорее всего, JavaFX позволяет создавать собственные компоненты и добавлять их в FXML-код под именем класса. Поэтому заменить  `<fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TasksList/TasksList.fxml"/>` на `<TasksList>` как-то можно, но о том, как это сделать, мне на данный момент неизвестно.

Что касается CSS-классов, то насколько я знаю, с ними и вообще с CSS дело обстоит в JavaFX очень плохо. В частности, с помощью CSS можно влиять в основном на декорацию, а на геометрию (даже на внутренние отступы) - практически нельзя. Это значит, что растянуть `<TasksList>` и `<TaskOverview>` с помощью CSS-класса, видимо, не получится и придётся идти на компромиссы.

Но если в JavaFX вообще возможно разрабатывать свои компоненты, то должен быть какой то способ в виде параметра задать контекстную геометрию, в частности заполнение доступного пространства.

Comment: Ну, по идее списку можно просто поставить высоту равную `Double.MAX_VALUE`, тогда он будет максимально расширяться по высоте, и при этом он не будет знать, в каком контейнере расположен.

Comment: @insolor, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Похоже я не уточнил, что должен список расширяться или нет - сам он этого знать не должен. Это должен решать тот компонент, который использует список. Обновлю вопрос и объявлю конкурс.

Comment: Сам компонент как раз должен знать, как ему себя вести внутри других компонентов (расширяться по максимуму, или занимать определенный размер), а внешние компоненты не должны за него это решать) Можно задать, что компонент пытается занять максимальную доступную ширину/высоты, а внешний компонент будет его ограничивать каким-то определенным размером.

Comment: @insolor Ну хорошо, допустим **одни и тот же компонент** в одном сайдбаре должен занимать всю доступную высоту, в другом - только необходимое для него пространство, в третьем контексте  - быть не больше определённый высоты, а в четвёртом - вообще быть относительно спозиционированным. Как Вы решите эту задачу в JavaFX, если Вы жестко зададите компоненту только какое-то одно из этих поведений?

Comment: Никак. В каждом контексте явно указывать как компоненты должны вести себя. Можно для многострочных компонентов типа того же списка всегда делать расширение на максимально доступное пространство по ширине и высоте, для однострочных - только по ширина, для кнопок - без расширения. Исключения из этого прописывать отдельно.

Comment: @insolor, ну что сказать, наверно это моя вина, что слишком много ожидал от JavaFX.